# create auto incremented field in access query

Tags: sql, function, ms-access, vba

I have a query in access and I need it to also have an auto incremented field. I can't add it physically to the table. I tried to create a function to the filed `inc : incfun(1)`

EDIT:
In my saved query I created a column in design mode called `INC : incfun(1)`  <--This is how I call my function. It outputs the data to the INC column.

Here is my function in module1 script file.

```
Dim inc As Integer
Option Compare Database

Function incfun(num As Integer) '1 is first passed to function as 1
inc = num + 1 '1 added to global variable inc
incfun = inc  'inc value passed back to output of function.
End Function
```

EDIT: Every time I refresh the datasheet it goes up by 1, but doesn't auto increment threw out all the rows. Anyway to make this work?

Comment: Depending on your table and the data you wish to retuen, it may be possible to do this without a function. You should post some sample data. Note that generated row numbers are of limited use, to say the least.

Comment: There is a solution, but there must be a unique field in the query. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
inc = incfun(1)
inc = incfun(1)
```

Both of these calls sets inc equal to the parameter (value = 1) + 1.  No matter how many times you call it `inc = incfun(1)`  will always set `inc` to 2.

Either use `inc = inc + 1` which I would have thought was the easier solution.

or replace the body of the function with:

```
inc = inc + n
incfun = inc
```

Comment: Doest seem to work. Just stays at 2 or 1. Doesnt auto increment.

Comment: Please add to your question the code that uses this function.  Both my suggestions would increment the global variable `inc` which your original code did not.

Comment: Every time I refresh it goes up by 1, but doesnt auto increment threw out all the rows.

Comment: `inc = num + 1 '1 added to global variable inc`  **This does not add 1 to inc**.  It sets `inc` to `num + 1`.  Since `num` is always 1, `inc` is always set to 2.  You need `inc = inc + n`.

Comment: n is not defined as anything so the output is just 0. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes and when i do that, everything becomes 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 Refresh 2,2,2,2,2 Refresh 3,3,3,3,3 and so on. It doesnt auto increment per row on the datasheet. I have the function inside the field name when I created the column in design view

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy for an hour. I only have one idea left. You do not use `Option Explicit` so if a variable does not exist, it will be created for you. Try `Public inc As Long` in case `inc` is being implicitly declared in several places.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Nope that does the same thing. Instead of incrementing each individual row, everything becomes 111111 refresh 222222 refresh 33333....etc. It increments the whole column by 1 every refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was trying to do something like this as well and I found that my function was only called once when I put it in with no arguments, since I didn't really need any. Just needed to have a variable that kept incrementing and returning it's value, but because the function was only called once, every row would be 1. I found by adding an integer argument that I didn't use and then giving a field in one of the tables as the argument, it forced the function to be called for each row therefore giving the desired result.

Dim inc As Integer
Option Compare Database

Public Function autoInc(i As Long) As Integer
inc = inc + 1
autoInc = inc
End Function

Then in the make table query.

index: autoInc([sometable].[numericalfield])